# ImportError: No module named google.protobuf

Tags: python, python-2.7, protocol-buffers

I am following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) and using the exact sample of addressbook.proto.

Post the content of compiler generated addressbook_pb2.py file as well.
When I run the following simple program, there is error saying, cannot find google.protobuf, any ideas how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

BTW, using Python 2.7 on Mac OSX.

```
from addressbook_pb2 import Person

p = Person()
p.email = "abc"

print p.email
```

**Here is the automated generated file addressbook_pb2.py,**

```
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: addressbook.proto

import sys
_b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='addressbook.proto',
  package='tutorial',
  syntax='proto2',
  serialized_pb=_b('\n\x11\x61\x64\x64ressbook.proto\x12\x08tutorial\"\xda\x01\n\x06Person\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x02(\t\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x02 \x02(\x05\x12\r\n\x05\x65mail\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12+\n\x05phone\x18\x04 \x03(\x0b\x32\x1c.tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber\x1aM\n\x0bPhoneNumber\x12\x0e\n\x06number\x18\x01 \x02(\t\x12.\n\x04type\x18\x02 \x01(\x0e\x32\x1a.tutorial.Person.PhoneType:\x04HOME\"+\n\tPhoneType\x12\n\n\x06MOBILE\x10\x00\x12\x08\n\x04HOME\x10\x01\x12\x08\n\x04WORK\x10\x02\"/\n\x0b\x41\x64\x64ressBook\x12 \n\x06person\x18\x01 \x03(\x0b\x32\x10.tutorial.Person')
)
_sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)



_PERSON_PHONETYPE = _descriptor.EnumDescriptor(
  name='PhoneType',
  full_name='tutorial.Person.PhoneType',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  values=[
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='MOBILE', index=0, number=0,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='HOME', index=1, number=1,
      options=None,
      type=None),
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
      name='WORK', index=2, number=2,
      options=None,
      type=None),
  ],
  containing_type=None,
  options=None,
  serialized_start=207,
  serialized_end=250,
)
_sym_db.RegisterEnumDescriptor(_PERSON_PHONETYPE)


_PERSON_PHONENUMBER = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='PhoneNumber',
  full_name='tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='number', full_name='tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber.number', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='type', full_name='tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber.type', index=1,
      number=2, type=14, cpp_type=8, label=1,
      has_default_value=True, default_value=1,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=128,
  serialized_end=205,
)

_PERSON = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Person',
  full_name='tutorial.Person',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='name', full_name='tutorial.Person.name', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='id', full_name='tutorial.Person.id', index=1,
      number=2, type=5, cpp_type=1, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='email', full_name='tutorial.Person.email', index=2,
      number=3, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='phone', full_name='tutorial.Person.phone', index=3,
      number=4, type=11, cpp_type=10, label=3,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[_PERSON_PHONENUMBER, ],
  enum_types=[
    _PERSON_PHONETYPE,
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=32,
  serialized_end=250,
)


_ADDRESSBOOK = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='AddressBook',
  full_name='tutorial.AddressBook',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='person', full_name='tutorial.AddressBook.person', index=0,
      number=1, type=11, cpp_type=10, label=3,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=252,
  serialized_end=299,
)

_PERSON_PHONENUMBER.fields_by_name['type'].enum_type = _PERSON_PHONETYPE
_PERSON_PHONENUMBER.containing_type = _PERSON
_PERSON.fields_by_name['phone'].message_type = _PERSON_PHONENUMBER
_PERSON_PHONETYPE.containing_type = _PERSON
_ADDRESSBOOK.fields_by_name['person'].message_type = _PERSON
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['Person'] = _PERSON
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['AddressBook'] = _ADDRESSBOOK

Person = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Person', (_message.Message,), dict(

  PhoneNumber = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('PhoneNumber', (_message.Message,), dict(
    DESCRIPTOR = _PERSON_PHONENUMBER,
    __module__ = 'addressbook_pb2'
    # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber)
    ))
  ,
  DESCRIPTOR = _PERSON,
  __module__ = 'addressbook_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:tutorial.Person)
  ))
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Person)
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Person.PhoneNumber)

AddressBook = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('AddressBook', (_message.Message,), dict(
  DESCRIPTOR = _ADDRESSBOOK,
  __module__ = 'addressbook_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:tutorial.AddressBook)
  ))
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(AddressBook)


# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

**Edit 1**

Tried `pip install protobuf`, met with the following error,

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): protobuf in /Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9 in /Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from protobuf)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from protobuf)
```

Here is the output of python version,

```
python -V
Python 2.7.11 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

**Edit 2**

Post exact error message,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1531, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 938, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/foo/personal/featureExtraction/protobuf_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from addressbook_pb2 import Person
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/foo/personal/featureExtraction/addressbook_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
```

**Edit 3**

error message when `import google`,

[image]

**Edit 4**

Output of `which pip`,

```
which pip
/Users/foo/miniconda2/bin/pip
```

Output of `sys.executable`,

/Users/foo/anaconda/bin/python

**Edit 5**

```
foo-mn1:featureExtraction foo$ sudo /Users/foo/miniconda2/bin/pip install protobuf
Password:
The directory '/Users/foo/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/foo/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): protobuf in /Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9 in /Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from protobuf)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from protobuf)
foo-mn1:featureExtraction foo$ sudo /Users/foo/miniconda2/bin/pip install google
The directory '/Users/foo/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/foo/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): google in /Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from google)
```

Comment: did you name one of your files "google.py"?

Comment: Lin Ma, you have two separate python installs running.  One on `/Users/foo/anaconda/` (this is the one called from your code) and one in /Users/foo/miniconda2/` (this is the one that you call when you typed `pip` from the terminal.  Consider finding the `scripts` or `bin` directory in `/Users/foo/anaconda` (whichever contains `pip`) and running `pip install ...` from within that directory.  This should install the protobuf package in the correct location for you to use it from within your current code setup.

Comment: @jedwards, nice catch and vote up. Wondering if I should use `pip install google` or `pip install protobuf`?

Comment: @jedwards, tried to use the full path to execute `pip`, see edit 5 section for the update. It seems it is said protobuf is already there. Then I tried to execute from PyCharm, met with the same issue, `No module named google.protobuf`, if you have any further thoughts, it will be great. :)

Comment: Try `cd /Users/foo/anaconda/bin` then `./pip install protobuf` -- or -- `cd /Users/foo/anaconda/bin` then `./python -m pip install protobuf`

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/890 This solves it.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Had the same issue and I resolved it by using  :

```
conda install protobuf
```

Comment: If without using `conda`, you'll have to do this: `sudo pip install google` and `sudo pip install protobuf`.

Comment: I use anaconda.  why do I have to do this package this way?  why doesn't `python -m pip install protobuf` work?

Comment: Not working for me. I am trying tensorflow version 1.4.

Comment: I tried it with pip3. `pip3 install protobuf` **works** but `pip3 install protobuf3` fails to install `google` package explicitly.

Answer (score 62):

You should run:

```
pip install protobuf
```

That will install Google protobuf and after that you can run that Python script.

As per [this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf).

Comment: Thanks David, vote up and tried and not working for me. Post the error message in Edit 1 section. If you have any further thoughts, it will be great.

Comment: why doesn't this work?  why do i have to do `conda install protobuf` instead?

Answer (score 22):

I also have this issue and have been looking into it for a long time. It seems that there is no such problem on python 3+. The problem is actually on google.protobuf

### **Solution 1:**

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip uninstall google
pip install google
pip install protobuf
pip install google-cloud
```

### **Solution 2:**

**create an `__init__.py` in "google" folder.**

```
cd /path/to/your/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google
touch __init__.py
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: This worked for me without the `pip install google-cloud` part.

Answer (score 21):

The reason for this would be mostly due to the **evil** command `pip install google`. I was facing a similar issue for `google-cloud`, but the same steps are true for `protobuf` as well. Both of our issues deal with a namespace conflict over the 'google' namespace.

If you executed the `pip install google` command like I did then you are in the correct place. The `google` package is actually not owned by Google which can be confirmed by the command `pip show google` which outputs:

```
 Name: google
 Version: 1.9.3
 Summary: Python bindings to the Google search engine.
 Home-page: http://breakingcode.wordpress.com/
 Author: Mario Vilas
 Author-email: mvilas@gmail.com
 License: UNKNOWN
 Location: <Path where this package is installed>
 Requires: beautifulsoup4
```

Because of this package, the `google` namespace is reserved and coincidentally `google-cloud` also expects namespace `google > cloud` and it results in a namespace collision for these two packages.

See in below screenshot namespace of `google-protobuf` as `google > protobuf`

[image: google-cloud namespace screenshot google > cloud > datastore]

**Solution** :- Unofficial `google` package need to be uninstalled which can be done by using `pip uninstall google` after this you can reinstall `google-cloud` using `pip install google-cloud` or `protobuf` using `pip install protobuf`

FootNotes :- Assuming you have installed the unofficial `google` package by mistake and you don't actually need it along with `google-cloud` package. If you need both unofficial `google` and `google-cloud` above solution won't work.

Furthermore, the unofficial 'google' package installs with it 'soupsieve' and 'beautifulsoup4'. You may want to also uninstall those packages.

Let me know if this solves your particular issue.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath happens!! even it took a lot of time for me also as it's not pretty obvious reason. But cheers I am happy it worked for your case :)

Comment: This is a huge security issue to allow some random dude to have a package called google.

Answer (score 7):

When `pip` tells you that you already have `protobuf`,
but PyCharm (or other) tells you that you don't have it,
it means that `pip` and PyCharm are using a different Python interpreter.
This is a very common issue, especially on a Mac, with no standard Python package management.

The best way to completely eliminate such issues is using a `virtualenv` per Python project, which is essentially a directory of Python packages and environment variable settings to isolate the Python environment of the project from everything else.

Create a `virtualenv` for your project like this:

```
cd project
virtualenv --distribute virtualenv -p /path/to/python/executable
```

This creates a directory called `virtualenv` inside your project.
(Make sure to configure your VCS (for example Git) to ignore this directory.)

To install packages in this `virtualenv`, you need to activate the environment variable settings:

```
. virtualenv/bin/activate
```

Verify that `pip` will use the right Python executable inside the `virtualenv`, by running `pip -V`. It should tell you the Python library path used, which should be inside the `virtualenv`.

Now you can use `pip` to install `protobuf` as you did.

And finally, you need to make PyCharm use this `virtualenv` instead of the system libraries. Somewhere in the project settings you can configure an interpreter for the project, select the Python executable inside the `virtualenv`.

Comment: Thanks janos, vote up, and do you know if google.protobuf works for python interpreter like miniconda2 or conda? If not I need to change a Python interpreter. Wondering what is the Python interpreter you are using?

Comment: I'm using the official Python 3.5 or Python 2.7 interpreters. But the method I describe should work with others too. Just follow the steps carefully as I described. All you need is make sure that you're using the same interpreter by `pip` on the command line and by PyCharm. And the best way to make sure of that is by using the same `virtualenv` in both, as I explained.

Answer (score 7):

On Mac OS - Installing tensorflow 1.3 - it will automatically remove other protobuf installs and install protobuf 3.4. However, this does not work and neither does installing or downgrading to any other protobuf version.

However I found a solution.
Not sure why this works - but on Mac OS this solved it.

```
pip install google
```

Comment: It works for me, but I have to install the two-command-tools as follows: `sudo pip install google` and `sudo pip install protobuf`.

Comment: `google` is not owned by Google as of 06 NOV 2017. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/4345

Answer (score 5):

Install protobuf:

```sh
pip install protobuf
```

Then import it like this:

```py
import google.protobuf
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same situation. And I find out it is because the pip should be updated. It may be the same reason for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem with google.protobuf import in Tensorflow and Python 3.7.5 that i had yesterday.

Check where is protobuf

```
pip show protobuf
```

If it is installed you will get something like this

```
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.6.1
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: 3-Clause BSD License
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: tensorflow, tensorboard
```

(If not, run `pip install protobuf` )

Now move into the *location* folder.

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Now run

```
touch google/__init__.py
```

Comment: Did not realize that protobuf sometimes installs to a different location than most other packages. `/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages` in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message as in the title, but in my case `import google` was working and `import google.protobuf` wasn't (on python3.5, ubuntu 16.04).

It turned out that I've installed `python3-google-apputils` package (using apt) and it was installed to '/usr/lib/**python3**/dist-packages/google/apputils/', while protobuf (which was installed using pip) was in "/usr/lib/**python3.5**/dist-packages/google/protobuf/" - and it was a "google" namespace collapse.

Uninstalling google-apputils (from apt, and reinstalling it using pip) solved the problem.

```
sudo apt remove python3-google-apputils
sudo pip3 install google-apputils
```

Answer (score 1):

To find where the name google clashes .... try this:

```
python3
```

then `>>> help('google')`

... I got info about google-auth:

```
NAME
    google

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    auth (package)
    oauth2 (package)
```

Also then try

```
pip show google-auth
```

Then

```
sudo pip3 uninstall google-auth
```

... and re-try `>>> help('google')`

I then see protobuf:

```
NAME
    google

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    protobuf (package)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue `Requirement already satisfied: protobuf` on windows when trying to install protobuf using `pip install protobuf`

```
     *************************************************************
     *** Could not import the Google protobuf Python libraries ***
     *** Try installing package 'python-protobuf' or similar.  ***
     *************************************************************
```

This was due to `python --version` pointed to v2.7 while `pip --version` pointed to the path of python v3.6.

Solution for this was to make sure to use pip from python2

```
python -m pip install protobuf
```

Answer (score 0):

[I had this issue](https://github.com/dgraph-io/pydgraph/issues/80) when using the Python wrapper for DGraph DB, which was somehow fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/dgraph-io/pydgraph/pull/81/files) (perhaps of use to someone).

Answer (score 0):

ImportError: cannot import name 'builder' from 'google.protobuf.internal' --
This is because the builder.py file is missing in google->protobuf->internal folder. You need to replace the google folder with a new one.

1. go to https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases
2. Download protobuf-23.4.tar.gz
3. Unzip the file. Go to python folder and copy "google" folder
4. Go to the venv-->Lib-->site-packages and replace the old "google" folder with the newly downloaded "google" folder. You will see that the builder.py file is again showing.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this Q while encountering this error when trying to execute the following code:

```py
from proto import Message
```

**Solution:**

```py
from google.protobuf.message import Message
```

Answer (score -1):

I am use jetson nano jetpack 4.6
easy way :

let unistall tensorflow and install again

it work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

If you are a windows user and try to start py-script in cmd - don't forget to type **python** before filename.

```
python script.py
```

I have "No module named google" error if forget to type it.