# Module Not Found Error: no module named google.protobuf with import tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am following [this guide](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-using-custom-dataset-745f30278446) and try to using "Making Inferences Using the Trained Object Detection Model" part, but i got a error like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUoRC.png)

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.protobuf'
```

main question is when i use import tensorflow ,it can not find google.protobuf, I've tried many way like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680593/importerror-no-module-named-google-protobuf)  to solve this error , but those olution does not work for me, still can not find google.protobuf, any idea can help me?This question is make me really desperate.

Comment: Have you tried `conda install -c anaconda protobuf`?

Comment: Hello Ahmad, thanks for your answer, but it still show no module error.

Comment: I think this error maybe cause by platfrom jupyter note, I use anaconda envrinoment to write python code import tensorflow, it work but jupyternotebook still not work, this is strange.

Comment: Please try again using `conda install protobuf` or `pip install protobuf`. Attaching a similar [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6341#issuecomment-536866409) for your reference.