# Loading a tokenizer on huggingface: AttributeError: 'AlbertTokenizer' object has no attribute 'vocab'

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm trying to load a `huggingface` model and tokenizer. This normally works really easily (I've done it with a dozen models):

```
from transformers import pipeline, BertForMaskedLM, BertForMaskedLM, AutoTokenizer, RobertaForMaskedLM, AlbertForMaskedLM, ElectraForMaskedLM
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")
```

But for some reason I'm getting an error when I'm trying to load this one:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sultan/BioM-ALBERT-xxlarge", use_fast=False)
model = AlbertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("sultan/BioM-ALBERT-xxlarge")
tokenizer.vocab
```

I found [this question](https://github.com/cl-tohoku/bert-japanese/issues/17) related, but it seems like this was an issue in the git repo itself and not on `huggingface`. I checked the actual repo where this model is saved on huggingface ([link](https://huggingface.co/sultan/BioM-ALBERT-xxlarge/tree/main)) and it clearly has a vocab file (`PubMD-30k-clean.vocab`) like the rest of the models I loaded.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some issue with the tokenizer. It works, if you remove `use_fast` parameter or set it true, then you will be able to display the vocab file.

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sultan/BioM-ALBERT-xxlarge", use_fast=True)
model = AlbertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("sultan/BioM-ALBERT-xxlarge")
tokenizer.vocab
```

Output:

```
{'intervention': 7062,
 '▁tongue': 6911,
 '▁kit': 8341,
 '▁biosimilar': 26423,
 'bank': 19880,
 '▁diesel': 20349,
 'SOD': 6245,
 'iri': 17739,
....
```

Comment: Without `use_fast=False` I get an error: `ImportError: 
AlbertConverter requires the protobuf library but it was not found in your environment. Checkout the instructions on the installation page of its repo: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/python#installation and follow the ones that match your environment.`. With `use_fast=True` I get the same error

Comment: Okay found the solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680593/importerror-no-module-named-google-protobuf). Need to run `conda install protobuf`

Comment: Sorry, this error didn't occur for me on colab. Happy you solved it!